# Date difference between rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date-difference

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t.trans_id, t.business_process_id, tsp.status, tsp.timestamp
  FROM tran_stat_p tsp, tran t
 WHERE t.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
       AND tsp.timestamp BETWEEN '1-jan-2008' AND SYSDATE
       AND t.business_process_id = 'ABC01'
```

It outputs data like this:

`trans_ID` `business_process_id` `status` `timestamp`
`14444400`          `ABC01`              `F`  `6/5/2008 12:37:36 PM`
`14444400`          `ABC01`              `W`  `6/6/2008 1:37:36 PM`
`14444400`          `ABC01`              `S`  `6/7/2008 2:37:36 PM`
`14444400`          `ABC01`              `P`  `6/8/2008 3:37:36 PM`
`14444401`          `ABC01`              `F`  `6/5/2008 12:37:36 PM`
`14444401`          `ABC01`              `W`  `6/6/2008 1:37:36 PM`
`14444401`          `ABC01`              `S`  `6/7/2008 2:37:36 PM`
`14444401`          `ABC01`              `P`  `6/8/2008 3:37:36 PM`

In addition to the above, I'd like to add a column which calculates the time difference (in days) between statuses W&F, S&W, P&S for every unique `trans_id`.

The idea is to figure out how long transactions are sitting in the various statuses before they are finally processed to status "P". The life cycle of a transaction is in the following order -> F -> W -> S -> P. Where F is the first status, and P is the final status.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` to retrieve the next timestamp value and calculated the time left in every status (F, W and S) and `TRUNC` to calculated days between as an integer :

```
SELECT t."trans_ID", t."business_process_id", tsp."status", tsp."timestamp", 
       LEAD("timestamp", 1) OVER (
                  PARTITION BY tsp."trans_ID" 
                  ORDER BY "timestamp") AS "next_timestamp",
       trunc(LEAD("timestamp", 1) OVER (
                        PARTITION BY tsp."trans_ID" 
                        ORDER BY "timestamp")) - trunc(tsp."timestamp") as "Days"
  FROM tran t
INNER JOIN tran_stat_p tsp ON t."trans_ID" = tsp."trans_ID" 
       AND tsp."timestamp" BETWEEN '01-jan-2008 12:00:00 AM' AND SYSDATE
WHERE t."business_process_id" = 'ABC01'
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04633/49/0

Comment: where in the above code does the query know to take the difference between W&F, S&W, P&S for every unique trans_id?

Comment: I ordered each unique trans_id by timestamp and then I calculated the day difference between the current timestamp and the timestamp of the following status : `trunc(LEAD("timestamp", 1) OVER (PARTITION BY tsp."trans_ID" ORDER BY "timestamp")) - trunc(tsp."timestamp") as "Days"`

Comment: can you describe what you mean by current timestamp and the timestamp of the code above? just trying to understand it in layman's terms!

Comment: By the current timestamp, I mean the timestamp of the current record. As example, for the record `14444400 ABC01 F 6/5/2008 12:37:36 PM`, the current timestamp is 6/5/2008 12:37:36 PM. The following status is `14444400 ABC01 W 6/6/2008 1:37:36 PM` so the following timestamp is 6/6/2008 1:37:36 PM

Answer (score 2):

The actual query would use [`LAG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm), which will give you a value from a prior row.

Your status codes won't sort as `F` -> `W` -> `S` -> `P`, which is why the query below has the big `CASE` statement for the `LAG` function's `ORDER BY` - it translates the status codes into a value that follows your transaction life cycle.

```
SELECT
  t.trans_id,
  t.business_process_id,
  tsp.status,
  tsp.timestamp,
  tsp.timestamp - LAG(timestamp) OVER (
    PARTITION BY tsp.trans_id
    ORDER BY
      CASE tsp.Status
        WHEN 'F' THEN 1
        WHEN 'W' THEN 2
        WHEN 'S' THEN 3
        WHEN 'P' THEN 4
        END) AS DaysBetween
FROM tran t
INNER JOIN tran_stat_p tsp ON t.trans_id = tsp.trans_id
WHERE tsp.timestamp BETWEEN DATE '2008-01-01' AND SYSDATE
  AND t.business_process_id = 'ABC01';
```

A couple more notes:

- The query is untested. If you have trouble please post some sample data and I'll test it.
- I used `DATE '2008-01-08'` to define Jnauary 1, 2008 because that's how Oracle (and ANSI) likes a date constant to look. When you use `1-jan-2008` you're relying on Oracle's default date format, and that's a session value which can be changed. If it's changed your query will stop working.

Comment: Then don't rely on Oracle's default date format, just use the TO_DATE() function: for example BETWEEN TO_DATE('2001-JAN-01', 'YYYY-MON-DD') AND SYSDATE.

Comment: TO_DATE is a valid choice. I prefer the [date literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) because, among other things, it's less typing :)

Comment: When i run the query, i get negative values for Daysbetween. If we're taking the differences of the statuses in the sequence outlined above, shouldnt there be a null value for statuses "F" and "P"?

Comment: If there's always a smooth progression from F to P status then the `DaysBetween` for `F` will be null because there isn't a prior ("LAG") row. I tried my query using the results from your list as a single table and got positive values, so if you need more help could you post sample data from the `tran` and `tran_stat` tables?

Answer (score 0):

Look into oracle window analytics. 
http://www.orafaq.com/node/55

You'll want to do a diff of your current row date and the lag of that date. 
Hope that makes sense.